# Unrecognized Feature: web-share (Youtube, Chrome)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, youtube, embed, devtools

I have a website that uses embedded videos (via youtube's share -> embed) and when I open DevTools in Chrome, I see an error that says:

Unrecognized feature: 'web-share'.

(anonymous)@react-dom.production….js?ver=16.14.0:184

when I click on the react-dom.production.... link, I see the following code:

```
  var si = /^(.*)[\\\/]/, Q = "function" === typeof Symbol && Symbol.for, Pc = Q ? Symbol.for("react.element") : 60103, gb = Q ? Symbol.for("react.portal") : 60106, Ma = Q ? Symbol.for("react.fragment") : 60107, Af = Q ? Symbol.for("react.strict_mode") : 60108, kc = Q ? Symbol.for("react.profiler") : 60114, Cf = Q ? Symbol.for("react.provider") : 60109, Bf = Q ? Symbol.for("react.context") : 60110, Hj = Q ? Symbol.for("react.concurrent_mode") : 60111, zd = Q ? Symbol.for("react.forward_ref") : 60112, lc = Q ? Symbol.for("react.suspense") : 60113, yd = Q ? Symbol.for("react.suspense_list") : 60120, Ad = Q ? Symbol.for("react.memo") : 60115, Ef = Q ? Symbol.for("react.lazy") : 60116, Df = Q ? Symbol.for("react.block") : 60121, zf = "function" === typeof Symbol && Symbol.iterator, od, xh = function(a) {
        return "undefined" !== typeof MSApp && MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction ? function(b, c, d, e) {
            MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function() {
                return a(b, c, d, e)
            })
        }
        : a
    }(function(a, b) {
        if ("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" !== a.namespaceURI || "innerHTML"in a)
            a.innerHTML = b;
        else {
            od = od || document.createElement("div");
            od.innerHTML = "<svg>" + b.valueOf().toString() + "</svg>";
            for (b = od.firstChild; a.firstChild; )
                a.removeChild(a.firstChild);
            for (; b.firstChild; )
                a.appendChild(b.firstChild)
        }
    }),
```

I have no idea what to make of this (supposedly, this is all code belonging to 184) as I'm new to JavaScript and React.

Can I fix this error on my website? If so, how? Or is this a Youtube issue?

I've tried looking everywhere online, but I'm not finding any references to my specific error. I thought about removing web-share from the iframe embed code, but it's a lot of videos to go through lol.

Example of the iframe embed code:

```html
<iframe width="241" height="143" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/youtubeid" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a problem with your website and doesn't seem to have negative effects. It's a bug in Chrome desktop, which doesn't support [Web Share](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Share_API).

This feature was [required as of Chrome 110](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/web-share-api-in-third-party-iframes/) to be added to the `allow` property of iframes if the iframe wants to use the [Web Share API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Share_API). YouTube specifies it in their embed code. But Chrome on desktop doesn't recognize it.

Chrome has a [test site](https://scrawny-bottlenose-somersault.glitch.me/share-from-iframes.html) for the new behavior, linked from [their own feature tracker](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6362499966304256) which also shows the warning.

You *could* try to only include the `web-share` bit if `navigator.canShare` exists. That would remove the warning. But it's harmless anyway. Something like:

```js
const myIframe = ...;
const hasWebShare = 'canShare' in navigator;
if (hasWebShare) {
    myIframe.allow = 'web-share';
}
```

But generally not worth it.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you!